# In android, how to make a phone link several wifi-direct group owner?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I want to realize an ad-hoc app with WI-FI direct in android. But here comes a problem: in my plan, each phone can be a group owner, so other phones can link it, and itself can link several other group owner(just as linking several WI-FI), the topology should be graph like. But through android doc, it seems like a phone can only link one WI-FI, so my topology just can be a tree. I know there is a way to deal with it in PC with WI-FI virtualization, but how to make it happen in android?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the Wifi Direct workings, the device can be only either Group owner or client connected to Group owner, so you can not make networks in your described way.

However, you could of course utilize the API to create a Access-point (The legacy support via CreateGroup function) into your device which other devices could connect to. And as you could connect to other Access-points, you could indeed realize the topology you desire with it.